# Report Application on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I'm trying to manually upgrade my Report Server 2005 project to Visual Studio 2010 Reports Application.

On Report Server 2005, I had a Shared Data Source and for each report I wrote a SQL query to fetch the data from the shared data source (the queries are not trivial, some of them use temporary tables populated at runtime).

Now on visual studio 2010 I can't find a way to create a Shared Data Source or even write SQL to fetch the data. anyone know how to use SQL queries on a vs2010 Report Application?

Comment: last i checked vs 2010 didn't support report projects, just rdl files.  at least, not yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now use Visual Studio 2010 to edit .rtproj report projects and .rdl reports.

You need VS10 SP1, then install the Data Tools for VS10, followed by the installation of SQL Server Express 2012 with Reporting Services and Data Tools.

I have gotten it to work like this.

[Are SSRS Reports supported in Visual Studio 2010 or 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333459/is-there-any-inbuilt-localization-resources-support-in-ssrs-using-visual-studio)